# How to know if I can add certain RAM to my notebook (ACER)

Tags: memory, hardware-rec

I have an old ASUS N76VZ which is broken. I have problems with RAM in newer ACER Aspire Nitro VN7 so I've decided to use RAM from the ASUS to this ACER.

**RAM:** 4GB 2Rx8 PC3 - 12800S - 11 - 11 F3

Since disassembling the ACER could be much more painful than the ASUS, I would like to find out if it fits there. There should be one empty slot in ACER so I would use it.

I have no idea if it will fit and if it will work.

Do you have any advices?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

crucial.com enter the make and model to see if there compatible, most likely from your description I'd say no, but you never know.You can also google "memory for make/model" and see if they match

Comment: Thanks, I've found this: http://www.crucial.com/usa/en/compatible-upgrade-for/Acer/aspire-vn7-591g#memoryResults I'm not sure but it seems to fit.

Comment: There's a N76VZ page they have:  http://www.crucial.com/usa/en/compatible-upgrade-for/ASUS/n76vz